# Having trouble using CSS and PHP

Tags: php, html, css, echo

I'm having trouble making CSS and PHP work together. as a project for class, I was instructed to make a clock with an image that changes based on the time. We were given a series of images, and then told that we also had to make the background color change with the time. (see full instructions here: https://github.com/susanBuck/notes/blob/master/04_PHP/07_Clock_exercise.md). I made my project using 3 files, clock.php, logic.php, and style.php. my index file is clock.php. the problem arises for me when I need to make the background change. in my logic file, there are a series of elseifs which i use to change the backround's url, so I added a var called $color.

```
if ( $hours < 11 && $hours > 5 && $am == "am" ) {
    $time = "php-morning.png";
    $color = "#865f86";
} elseif ( $hours >= 11 && $am == "am" || $hours > 4 && $am == "pm" ) {
    $time = "php-afternoon.png";
    $color = "#2c87c8";
} elseif ( $hours >= 4 && $hours < 8 && $am == "pm" ) {
    $time = "php-evening.png";
    $color = "#c7b02f";
} elseif ( $hours >= 8 && $am == "pm" || $hours < 5 && $am == "am" ) {
    $time = "php-night.png";
    $color = "#180629";
}
```

and then in my stylesheet, I made the background equal to:

```
 body {
    background-color: <? echo $color ?>;
}
```

I also included the tag at the beginning of the stylesheet to make it read as a css file. 
(`<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");?>`) but the color isn't changing.  I tried echoing out just $color to make sure it was working properly, and it was.  my full github repository is here: http://is.gd/WVPuHG any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: If short open tags are not on, change `<? echo $color ?>` to `<?php echo $color ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$color` is not defined in the `style.php` file, only in the `logic.php` file. You've correctly `require`d it in `clock.php`, but you should also require it in `style.php`

Just because you linked to `style.php` as a stylesheet, doesn't mean PHP variables are magically passed to it - it is a separate request.

Comment: You can still Accept it :p